# Two Triggers saving into one trigger file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Original triggers written in one sql file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "LOCATION_TRIGGER"
BEFORE INSERT ON BBT_LOCATIONS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  IF :new.LOCATIONID < 1000 
  THEN :new.LOCATIONID := :new.LOCATIONID;
  ELSE
  :new.LOCATIONID := LOCATIONID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;
END LOCATION_TRIGGER;

---------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ROUTESTOP_TRIGGER"
BEFORE INSERT ON BBT_ROUTESTOP
FOR EACH ROW    

DECLARE
  matches varchar2(4);

BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO matches FROM BBT_LOCATIONS WHERE LOCATIONID = :new.STOP_REFERENCE;
  IF (match <> 1)
  THEN
   SELECT LOCATIONID into :new.STOP_REFERENCE
   FROM BBT_LOCATIONS
   WHERE NAME = :new.NAME;
  END IF;

END ROUTESTOP_TRIGGER;
```

When this is ran all of the code for both triggers goes into the LOCATION_TRIGGER and all that goes into the ROUTESTOP_TRIGGER is

```
create or replace
```

First time writing triggers. Feel like my syntax must be wrong but I cannot see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are running this from sqlplus, put a single `/` on its own line at the end of each trigger in order to execute the previous block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a forward slash on a new line after each trigger to execute the command in the buffer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "LOCATION_TRIGGER"
.......
END LOCATION_TRIGGER;
/
```

Comment: That fixed it. Wow, sql is testing my patience haha. Thanks a lot man.
Just problems with the actual sql now.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be,

```
 IF (matches <> 1) instead of  IF (match <> 1) in the code?
```

The variable declared is

```
matches varchar2(4); but you are using match inside
```

this will through an error.

Comment: Yeah there were a few errors with the SQL that I changed afterwards, it was just the 2 saving into one trigger that was causing me issues. Thanks though.